# Выравнивание текста по центру в select

Tags: jquery, form, select

```
<select name="product_id" class="select">
    <option value="">Выберите Расцветку</option>
    <option value="12">Черный</option>
    <option value="11">Коричневый</option>
</select>
```

Стилями не получается выровнять по центру! 
Подскажите решение на `JS`.

Answer (score 5):

Можно через `CSS`:

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
  text-align-last: center;
}
```

```html
<select name="product_id" class="select">
  <option value="">Выберите Расцветку</option>
  <option value="12">Черный</option>
  <option value="11">Коричневый</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.block {
    text-align : center;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <select name="product_id" class="select">
        <option value="">Выберите Расцветку</option>
        <option value="12">Черный</option>
        <option value="11">Коричневый</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

либо же так

```
.block option {
    text-align : center;
}

.block select{
    text-align : center;
}
```

что-то из этих 3х вариантов сработает

Comment: J2ee ???????????